# Can a server have more than one SSH key pair?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, key-pair

I have an EC2 server on AWS. I created a key pair upon first time connecting to the server (following whatever default steps on the console).

Now I want to login to the same server from a different machine. What is the best way to do so? Do I have to email my public key to the other machine?

I tried to create more key pairs on the AWS console, but can't figure out to additional key pairs to the server. Is that even possible?

**Update:**

This is not a duplicate question. My goal is not to associate two key pairs with one server. I am trying to find a way to login to a server from a different computer, whether to use the same key pair, another key pair or even a different user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an Amazon EC2 instance is launched from an Amazon Linux AMI (and several other Linux AMIs, too), the public half of the keypair selected at launched will automatically be copied to:

```
/home/users/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

When you later attempt to login to the `ec2-user` by providing the private half of the keypair, the two halves will be compared and, if they match, you will be permitted to login as that user.

You can allow another person to login to the `ec2-user` by either:

- Giving them the same private keypair (bad for security), *OR*
- By creating a keypair for them (via `ssh-keygen`) and adding the public half of that keypair to the above file

Alternatively, you could create a **new user** on the machine for them, then add the keypair to the above file within their user directory.

See: [Add New User Accounts with SSH Access to a Linux Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/)

So, to login to that EC2 instance from a different computer, you will need the private keypair on that different computer. It's just like a password.

Or, you could create a new keypair on that computer and copy the public keypair to the `authorized_keys` file on the target instance.

All of this is really Linux stuff, rather than something specific to Amazon EC2.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create multiple key pairs for an ec2 server; however you can create multiple users and through that give access.

Id advice creating multiple users and giving access via ssh with key authentication.  I have included a link below with the walkthrough.

With that being said you Create a new user, then
allocate permissions and privileges.  Next you generate a key - certificate. And finally, you associate the certificate to the user.

https://debian-administration.org/article/530/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password